# Can someone explain what 'diskutil cs revert' does?

Tags: ssd, disk-utility, partition, core-storage

so I was following some instructions to get my windows bootcamp partition to resize in disk utility, because after upgrading to Yosemite I was unable to resize my partition to give one side more space (although I had free space).
I followed the commands I saw on multiple different support links and they all seemed to be the same and worked for those who had problems, so I followed it through and it did indeed work. It was to find the logical volume id though the

> diskutil cs list

then to use

> diskutil cs revert

However, In disk utility my main disk (the one at the top) has been renamed to the name of the SSD hardware with my two partitions underneath, rather than just 'Macintosh HD' with the two partitions.

[image]

So I was wondering, what does this command do, are there any effects of it changing the name in disk utility and are there any consequences of this command?
Thanks in advance!

--
MacBook Pro 13" Late 2013 Retina 2.4Ghz Intel Core i5 256GB SSD OS X Yosemite 10.10.3

Comment: and you get some up vote for nice question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diskutil cs revert` turns off the Core Storage volume manager for that volume. The Yosemite installer turns it on in case it's needed later (mostly for FileVault), but if you don't actually need it (e.g. for FileVault a Fusion disk) it doesn't do anything useful.

If you aren't using FileVault or a Fusion disk, what Core Storage mostly does is confuse Disk Utility, limiting its ability to dynamically resize and rearrange volumes, and preventing it from displaying the disk structure properly. That "251 GB APPLE SSD SD..." thing is what Disk Utility *should* be displaying there, because "Macintosh HD" and "BOOTCAMP" are both volumes within the physical SSD. With Core Storage, it was showing BOOTCAMP as somehow part of Macintosh HD, which it isn't at all.

Comment: Thanks so much, really concise answer and that's defused my worries. Thanks!